# Cocoa: distinguish input device / scrollWheel: as mouse-scroll wheel and TrackPad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, appkit

I am looking for a method to reliably distinguish within `[NSResponder scrollWheel:]` if the users input device has a one-dimensional scroll-wheel or a two dimensional trackPad/magicMouse?

In the first I would like to implement a different behavior. 
But just taking a look on the deltaX of the `NSEvent` would be a little weak.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the private method call `[theEvent _scrollPhase]` to tell whether the device is using inertial scrolling, which indicates an Apple-supplied input device. (Note: this won't work if the user has disabled inertial scrolling)

Comment: You don't need private API to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Use the event's subtype:

```
enum {
   NSMouseEventSubtype           = NX_SUBTYPE_DEFAULT,
   NSTabletPointEventSubtype     = NX_SUBTYPE_TABLET_POINT,
   NSTabletProximityEventSubtype = NX_SUBTYPE_TABLET_PROXIMITY
   NSTouchEventSubtype             = NX_SUBTYPE_MOUSE_TOUCH
};
```

This will work even with inertial scrolling disabled.