# Distinguishing actual scrollwheel vs trackpad vs tablet scrolling events

Tags: macos, cocoa, mousewheel, trackpad

It seems scrollWheel: has to be it, for receiving these.  Unfortunately the trackpad's scrolling deltas are orders of magnitude higher than a mouse's, so the scroll speed is psychotically high.  Ergo I need to distinguish them so that I can apply an appropriate dampener.

The docs perplexingly note that while you usually do this by checking NSEvent's subtype, in scrollWheel: specifically that doesn't work.  But they don't say what you should do.  Experimentation has shown me that while trackpad scrolls are indeed not correctly typed as NSTouchEventSubtype, their type *is* different from mouse wheel scrolls - NSTabletPointEventSubtype vs NSMouseEventSubtype.  The problem is, NSTabletPointEventSubtype is also what's used for genuine tablet scroll events, and the deltas in those are even *more* ridiculously high.  So I need to distinguish those too.

NB: Similar prior questions include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5217680/790079), where the only suggestion was inference based on an undocumented API, or others featuring similar hacks.  Some seem to be recommending that you ignore scrollWheel: entirely and track touch events manually, but that seems to be a lot of redundant work that might break in future OS releases.

Comment: I'm getting scrollWheel event's with `subtype == NSEventSubtypeApplicationActivated` which is documented as _"No overview available"_.. or otherwise, it isn't documented.  Worse still, when `[event hasPreciseScrollingDeltas]` is set, I only see values changing in the non-precise fields.  This API seems a mess.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `[event hasPreciseScrollingDeltas]` is what you're looking for. It's available in OS X 10.7.